# Inserting double quotes into MySql db

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I need to insert a value which contains double quotes into MySql db:

```
import MySQLdb
cursor = db.cursor()
sql_pattern = 'INSERT INTO Table(column1, column2, column3....) VALUES("{0}".....)'
data_object_array = get_data_object_array()
for item in data_object_array():
  sql = sql_pattern.format(item["attr1"], item["attr2"]....)
  cursor.execute(sql)
```

I have an error of

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'data" fdsfds5454 "data2"")\' at line 1')
```

where `"data" fdsfds5454 "data2"` is the data which contains `item["attr1"]`

How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**DON'T, DON'T, DON'T** use `.format` for SQL queries.  Use built-in DB escaping mechanism:

```
sql_pattern = 'INSERT INTO Table(column1, column2, column3...) VALUES(%s, %s.....)'

...
  cursor.execute(sql_pattern, (item["attr1"], item["attr2"]...,))
```

`.exectue` will substitute each %s with proper (safe!) string representation of value, be it string, integer, float, etc.  Not there are no additional quotation marks around `%s` in `sql_patter`, as `.execute` will add them depending on argument type.

Comment: When I'm trying to insert many argument, I can't: `sql_pattern = 'INSERT INTO MyTable(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'
a = '"data" fdsfds "data2"'
cursor.execute(sql_pattern, (a, "aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff"))` -- `TypeError: execute() takes at most 3 arguments (9 given)`

Comment: Sorry, you have to pass n-tuple, not arguments one by one.